# Access PDF Bookmarks from Browser with Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, web

OK, here's the scoop.  I have an almost completely locked-down (view only) PDF from the post office.  I must create a web application where a user can type in a bookmark name that will bring up the correct page in the PDF.  I know that there is no way to programmatically jump to a particular bookmark.  There are no named destinations in the document and no way to create them.  Is there a way to programmatically extract page numbers from the bookmarks in a PDF document via JavaScript?  Can I loop through the bookmarks to find the right one and read the page number?  Why should this be so blasted difficult?

Comment: Are you locked into using Acrobat Reader and a particular server solution?

Comment: Hi, Plinth.  We're using IIS for all our main stuff but Apache is available.  The PDFs will be served out of an Oracle database.  I was planning on writing some sort of ASP page or, conversely, serving the web page directly from Oracle - difficult to separate the page from the data in that case but it's doable.  Reader is our default but I have used PDF.js and Sumatra plug-ins in Firefox.  Not sure how to handle IE, which is our default browser.  It's giving me trouble just displaying a basic PDF in an object or embed tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My company, [Atalasoft](http://www.atalasoft.com), makes an [Ajax/asp.net control](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/html-viewer-sdk) that has the capabilities to do what you want.  It will let you display the PDFs and on the server side, it's not too hard to pull out the bookmarks and the destinations and send them to the client control.

Essentially, you are replacing the Acrobat (or other) viewer with an image-based viewer which, on the server side, has dissected the PDF and can tell the viewer where to go.

Here is some sample code for pulling out bookmarks - this code looks more complex than you might think it should be and that's because the bookmarks in PDF are a full tree.

```
delegate void BookmarkReceiver(PdfBookmark bookmark);

public void VisitBookmarks(PdfBookmarkList bookmarks, BookmarkReceiver receiever)
{
    foreach (PdfBookmark mark in bookmarks)
    {
        receiver(mark);
        VisitBookmarks(mark.Children);
    }
}

// here's a matcher:

IList<PdfBookmark> FindBookmarksWithName(string s, PdfBookmarkTree tree)
{
    List<PdfBookmark> marks = new List<PdfBookmark>();
    VisitBookmarks(tree.Bookmarks, mark => if (mark.Text == s) marks.Add(mark));
    return marks;
}
```

Of course, the visitor could be modified to take a predicate and short-circuit if you only wanted to find one.

Now to figure out which page you're suppose to go to if you have a particular bookmark is not as simple as pulling out the page index.  This is because bookmarks don't have to go to a particular page.  A bookmark has an action associated with it and that action may be a list of things to do when the bookmark is clicked on.  For example, I could make a click action that is a list of two actions that first swaps the first and last pages and then goes to the first page.

So what you do is get the click action and iterate over the list and try to find a "Go To View" action, and then identify the destination as a page index and grab that.

Yes, this is many more steps than you would think because PDF is more richly specified than it needs to be.  A destination page could be an indexed page but it could also be a page in a different document on your local file system, so we do need check to see what we have every step of the way.

Comment: This looks like it may work although, as you say, Adobe makes it more complicated than it needs to be. Also it may be a difficult sell - I'm checking with our software overlords to see if we are currently licensing software from you. Looking again at the problem, I was thinking that a better idea than scanning the bookmarks each time may be to pull out the bookmark page number and store it in the database up front while processing the PDF - that should make this whole circus a lot simpler.  Off-hand, do you know if there is a way to use GhostScript or some other scripting mechanism to do this?

Comment: Spoke to my boss and to our customer - I guess I was trying to provide more functionality than they actually needed.  Thanks to Plinth and everyone else who took a look at this problem for me.